# Keycloak Hardcoded Group Mapper

Tags: keycloak

So I have been adding a specific group to just one set of federated users in Keycloak with the hardcoded ldap group mapper.  This happens on user registration and successfully adds them to the group in KC.  However, I also need this same group to map back to the federated ldap and this is not happening due I am presuming to this line of code in the mapper (which I am looking at on keycloak github):
`@Override  public void onRegisterUserToLDAP(LDAPObject ldapUser, UserModel localUser, RealmModel realm)`

My issue is that I cannot find this file anywhere on my Keycloak server (HardcodedLDAPGroupStorageMapper.java) to try commenting it out and am also presuming (lots of that going on right now!!) that it is renamed or hidden in some other jar file or something...
Would appreciate any help on this or another method to be able to add users to a group for just one of my three federated clients that will also allow it to sync back to the ldap server.

Comment: I should add that I really don't need the group to be locked down as the hardcoded mapper does, I just need it added on initial user registration for the single federation and that is the only way I have been able to achieve that so far.  In fact, it would be a better scenario if I was able to delete the group from the user at a later point in time which you cannot do if the group is hard coded.

Comment: Have you tried adding the group in Keycloak and your federated ldap, configure it as a default group in Keycloak and use the GroupLDAPStorageMapper instead?

Comment: I can't add it as the default group as that will add the group to all users regardless of which federation they come from.